# What is "Ticket Options" Referring to in Domain Controller Event Logs?

Tags: domain-controller, kerberos, windows-event-log

I'm trying to figure out what Ticket Options is referring too within this event log off my domain controller. It is in response to a kerberos authentication request.

```
AgentDevice=WindowsLog
AgentLogFile=Security
PluginVersion=7.1.3.613248
Source=Security
Computer=DOMAINCONTROLLERHOSTNAME
User=SYSTEM
Domain=NT AUTHORITY
EventID=672
EventIDCode=672
EventType=8
EventCategory=9
RecordNumber=95767528
TimeGenerated=1418246782
TimeWritten=1418246782
Level=0
Keywords=0
Task=0
Opcode=0
Message=Authentication Ticket 
Request:
   User Name:  1234567
   Supplied Realm Name: MYREALM.COM
   User ID:   DOMAIN\1234567
   Service Name:  krbtgt
   Service ID:  MAPLE\krbtgt
   Ticket Options:  0x50800000   <-------------
   Result Code:  -
   Ticket Encryption Type: 0x17
   Pre-Authentication Type: 2
   Client Address:  10.12.32.12
   Certificate Issuer Name:
   Certificate Serial Number: 
   Certificate Thumbprint:
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 4120](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4120.txt) has your answer deep on page 74 and 75. It reads:

> kdc-options
>         This field appears in the KRB_AS_REQ and KRB_TGS_REQ requests to
>         the KDC and indicates the flags that the client wants set on the
>         tickets as well as other information that is to modify the
>         behavior of the KDC.  Where appropriate, the name of an option may
>         be the same as the flag that is set by that option.  Although in
>         most cases, the bit in the options field will be the same as that
>         in the flags field, this is not guaranteed, so it is not
>         acceptable simply to copy the options field to the flags field.
>         There are various checks that must be made before an option is
>         honored anyway.
>
> The kdc_options field is a bit-field, where the selected options
>         are indicated by the bit being set (1), and the unselected options
>         and reserved fields being reset (0).

Following that is a list of the options available. There's other information in the RFC advising that some options aren't supported by older standards, etc.